# Show that for any $f$, $\sum_{i=0}^n f(x_i)\ell_i(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n f[x_0,x_1,\dots, x_i]\prod_{j=0}^{i-1}(x-x_j)$

Tags: numerical-methods, lagrange-interpolation

> Using the functions $\ell_i$, which are polynomials that depend on the nodes, and based on nodes $x_0,\ldots, x_n$, show that for any $f$, $$\sum_{i=0}^n f(x_i)\ell_i(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n f[x_0,x_1,\dots, x_i]\prod_{j=0}^{i-1}(x-x_j)$$

**My Proof:** Recall from Lagrange Interpolation Polynomial,
$$\ell_i(x)=\prod_{\substack{j=0 \\ j\neq i}}^n\dfrac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}.$$
Thus, 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=0}^n f(x_i)\ell_i(x) & =\sum_{i=0}^n f(x_i)\prod_{\substack{j=0 \\ j\neq i}}^n\dfrac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j} \\
& =\sum_{i=0}^n f(x_i)\prod_{\substack{j=0 \\ j\neq i}}^n\dfrac{1}{x_i-x_j}\prod_{\substack{j=0 \\ j\neq i}}^n(x-x_j) \\
& \stackrel{\text{?}}{=}\sum_{i=0}^n f[x_0,x_1,\dots,x_i]\prod_{\substack{j=0 \\ j\neq i}}^n(x-x_j) \\
& \stackrel{\text{?}}{=} \sum_{i=0}^n f[x_0,x_1,\dots,x_i]\prod_{j=0}^{i-1}(x-x_j)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

So I am unsure of the last two steps can someone help me understand if the logic is correct or do I need to prove each step more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third equality is false. The quantity $f[x_0,...,x_i]$ is the divided difference of $f$ and not the quantity $f(x_i)\prod_{j\neq i} \frac{1}{x_i-x_j}$.

For proving these two formulations (The Lagrange and the Newton ones) are equal, you need to use the unicity of the interpolation polynomial. If you define $P_n(x)=\sum_i f[x_0,...,x_i] \prod_{j=0}^{i-1} (x-x_j)$, you can check that $P_n$ has degree $n$ and $P_n(x_i)=f(x_i)$, so $P_n$ is the Lagrange polynomial. =)

Comment: I have another question asking me to prove $f[x_0,,x_1,\dots,x_n]=\sum_{i=0}^n f(x_i) \prod_{\substack{j=0 \\ j\neq i}}^n (x_i-x_j)^{-1}$ can this be applying to my problem?

Comment: Also, I am not 100% clear on how to do the proof the way you suggested? Can you restate it?

Comment: I guess the equality you're talking about can be proved by induction. It seems to be true at least for the first $n$...
I think you can prove your equality by replacing $f[x_0,...,x_n]$ in your previous calculus.
The method I gave you is the fastest, but you can still find the result with your equality I think.

Comment: To do the proof the way I suggested you have to verify that The Lagrange polynomial and the Newton polynomial are the unique interpolation polynomial, that is they satisfy $deg(P)=n$ and $P(x_i)=f(x_i)$. It can be shown (easily) that the interpolation polynomial is unique.

Comment: Please tell me if I'm not clear enough. I have some references on the subject if you want, but only in french.